# Table caption is hidden when I use tabularray

Tags: labels, tabularray, springer

I'm using Springer Nature LaTeX template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/myxmhdsbzkyd). I used https://www.latex-tables.com to generate a simple table:

[image]

Here is the latex code

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table X}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tblr}{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {Q[219]Q[198]Q[198]},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{0.396\linewidth,c},
  cell{2}{1} = {r=2}{c},
  vline{2-4} = {2}{},
  vline{3-4} = {3}{},
  hline{2-4} = {2-3}{},
}
  & H &   \\
V & 1 & 2 \\
  & 3 & 4 
\end{tblr}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For some reason the table does not show the caption:

[image]

Where is my mistake? Note that I already included the required package \usepackage{tabularray}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table, which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: I updated the post to include the whole code, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, we can try to use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

I have tried the following code (adapted from your MWE) in Overleaf with the version 2.2 of the considered format ("Springer Nature LaTeX Template").

I have loaded in my Overleaf project the latest version of `nicematrix.sty`
(version 6.21a 2023/07/17) because the "TexLive 2022 of Overleaf" has an old version of `nicematrix`. It seems to work.

```
%Version 2.1 April 2023
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

\usepackage{nicematrix}  % <-------------

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{caption-above}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[caption = My own caption,columns-width=1cm]
& \Block{1-2}{H} \\
\Block{2-1}{V} & \Block[hvlines]{2-2}{}1 & 2 \\
               & 3 & 4 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for editing your question.

I test it now with my installation of LaTeX and (apparently old) version of `sn-jnl` document class. By it I can't reproduce your problem, however, with recent version of it on Overleaf, this is not the case anymore. It seems that it not support `tabularray` package.

I suggest you to ask Overleaf stuff for support. So far you can )only) use proposed changes of table code:

[image]

I wee bit rewrite your table code (this has not any influence on caption):

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{width=0.25\linewidth,
             hline{2-Z}={2-Z}{solid}, vline{2-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
             colspec = {Q[c] X[c] X[c]},
             cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{c},
             cell{2}{1} = {r=2}{c},
             }
  & H &   \\
V & 1 & 2 \\
  & 3 & 4
\end{tblr}
\caption{Table X \label{tableX}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest template (linked above)? because when I copy your code to template Version 2.1  I get couple of error messages (Undefined control sequence.) and (Missing number, treated as zero.).

Comment: Sorry, I use older template. With recent on Overleaf doesn't work as it is expected. It seems that it support only `tabular`  (without of vertical rules). I suggest you to contact Overleaf support for help.

Comment: I will, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Author of https://www.latex-tables.com here, under the button "Generate", you can select your preferred LaTeX environment. Default is "auto", but you can select "tabular" if you can't use "tabularray".