# Formatting caption for talltblr

Tags: tables, format

I used talltblr for tables to solve an issue discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690324/table-caption-is-hidden-when-i-use-tabularray)

But now the label font is not bold. I tried to change captionsetup setting without luck. Also, how can I put the caption below the table if possible.

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table X}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption={TableX},
  label = {TableX},
]{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {Q[219]Q[198]Q[198]},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{0.396\linewidth,c},
  cell{2}{1} = {r=2}{c},
  vline{2-4} = {2}{},
  vline{3-4} = {3}{},
  hline{2-4} = {2-3}{},
}
  & H &   \\
V & 1 & 2 \\
  & 3 & 4 
\end{talltblr}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your code is not minimal (see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). Did you try to put `\caption{Table X}` after the tabular? But it is good style to put table caption always above the table.

Comment: As for the caption, you can [redefine the template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681927/47927).

Comment: Yes. Thank you. The only remaining challenge is the text format for the label (Table). I want it to be in bold.